# Python - Trouble with Twython api

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, twython, notin

I've written a python script which uses Twython to interact with twitter. It downloads the followers list into a variable (followers), and the list of people I'm following into another variable (friends). It should then automatically follow everybody who follows me, but who I am not yet following.

```
for fol in followers:
    if fol not in friends:
        twitter.create_friendship(fol)
```

The error I'm getting is that `twitter.create_friendship` requires exactly one argument, but it is being given two. I don't see how it is being given two arguments, I can only see the one.

Comment: Here is the documentation for [`create_friendship`](http://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create_friendship#twython.Twython.create_friendship) which points to the [`friendships.create`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/friendships/create) documentation.

Comment: When you call a function in python, the object you call it on is passed as the first parameter. This is why all class methods take `self` as the first parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`create_friendship()` is a bound method, which means it'll take just the `self` argument. It doesn't take any other *positional* arguments, but you are passing in `fol`, giving it *two* arguments now (`self` and `fol`).

The method should be passed *keyword* arguments instead:

```
twitter.create_friendship(user_id=fol)
```

if `fol` is a user id, or

```
twitter.create_friendship(screen_name=fol)
```

if `fol` is a screen name.